# How to make an ANTLR3 VBScript parser see '&htmlTag' as two tokens?

Tags: vbscript, antlr, antlr3

While parsing VBScript code with my ANTLR3 parser, I found it processes everything except

```
x = y &htmlTag
```

This code is obviously meant as "x = y & htmlTag". (Me, I put spaces around operators in any language, but the code I am parsing is not mine.) The lexer should find the longest string that is a valid token, right? So that should work fine here: As '&h' is not followed by text that results in a hex literal, the lexer should decide that this is not a hex literal and the longest valid token is the operator '&'. Followed by an identifier.

But if my grammar says:

```
HexOrOctalLiteral :
    (   ( AMPERSAND H HexDigit ) => AMPERSAND H HexDigit+
    |   ( AMPERSAND O OctalDigit ) => AMPERSAND O OctalDigit+
    )
    AMPERSAND?
    ;
ConcatenationOperator: AMPERSAND;
fragment AMPERSAND   : '&';
fragment HexDigit    : Digit | A | B | C | D | E | F;
fragment OctalDigit  : '0' .. '7';
fragment H           : 'h' | 'H';
```

My parser complains: required (...)+ loop did not match anything at character 'h' when processing the '&htmlTag'. It appears the lexer has already decided that it has found a HexOrOctalLiteral and will no longer consider a concat operator. My grammar has k=1, not sure if that is relevant here because setting it higher for this rule using 'options' seems to make no difference.

What am I missing?

Comment: Octal literals in VBScript begin with `&O`. You don't appear to be checking for the `O`.

Comment: Quite correct. Thanks, updated the question. Fixing this does not make the parsing work but does change the error message to 'mismatched character 'h' expecting set null'. Seems like the parser still wants to give me a HexOrOctalLiteral rather than a concat operator?

Comment: By the way: If I remove the syntactic predicates, I get "required (...)+ loop did not match anything at character 't' ". Also not what I am aiming for.